# Moment.js incorrect formatting

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Moment suddenly started to format dates incorrectly. Like, completely changing them. I don't understand why. I made a short video so you can see what's going on here: https://youtu.be/WPLDiiWsfAo

Here's some of the code that's working wrong:

```
activeProject() {
  let proj = { ...this.$store.state.activeProject };
  if (proj.Start) {
    debugger;
    proj.Start = moment(proj.Start).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    proj.End = moment(proj.End).subtract(1, "days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    return proj;
  } else return {};
},
```

`proj.Start = "2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"` outputs `02/28/2021`
`proj.End = "2021-03-08T00:00:00.000Z"` outputs `03/06/2021`

So after formatting with moment, it takes 1 days off of `proj.Start` and  `proj.End`. Why would it be doing this?

Comment: I can assure you that moment has not "suddenly started to format dates incorrectly".  It is your code that is incorrect.  Don't blame highly used very solid built in modules without very good proof.

Comment: Did you watch the video? Are you going to offer any advice or did you just comment to be snarky and tell me I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: I need to mention that the video was helpful to your question. Please do not remove it from Youtube... For future SO readers. ;)

Comment: Excellent use of a video! If only you could upload them on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ISO 8601 standard, [the `Z` means UTC (Coordinated Universal Time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), which in practice is London, England Time.

Your issue is reproduced below if you are in a timezone west of London, England (like me) and the current time time in London just passed 00:00 (like right now as I write this answer). That snippet would ouput the right values for one being in a timezone East of London, at the same moment.

```js
let proj = {Start: "2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z", End:"2021-03-08T00:00:00.000Z"}

proj.Start = moment(proj.Start).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
proj.End = moment(proj.End).subtract(1, "days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");

console.log(proj.Start, "expected: 03/01/2021")
console.log(proj.End, "expected: 03/07/2021")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Notice without the `Z` now...

```js
let proj = {Start: "2021-03-01T00:00:00.000", End:"2021-03-08T00:00:00.000"}

proj.Start = moment(proj.Start).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
proj.End = moment(proj.End).subtract(1, "days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");

console.log(proj.Start, "expected: 03/01/2021")
console.log(proj.End, "expected: 03/07/2021")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

So your issue is specififying a date/time relative to UTC while it seems it is not what you want.

Your solution would be to remove the final `Z` from the data used...

> moment(...) is local mode. Ambiguous input (without offset) is assumed to be local time. Unambiguous input (with offset) is adjusted to local time.

[Moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I just need to find out why the Z is being saved into the data to begin with and it should be good to go. Thank you so much!

Comment: A quick "patch" could be: `proj.Start = moment(proj.Start.slice(0,proj.Start.length-1).format("MM/DD/YYYY");`... To remove that `Z`. ;) But I advise you to look for better solution about the data itself.